# Unable to perform real time video processing in RaspberryPi using Webcam

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, webcam, video-processing, opencv3.0

I wrote a code to detect a white color using a Webcam (*Logitech C310 HD Webcam*) in **RaspberryPi 3B+**. 
Code will perform the following functions:

1. Capture the video using `cv2.VideoCapture (0)`
2. Grab each frame of video and look for white objects in that frame.
3. If a white object is present in that frame, code will encircle it and will print White.
4. Real video and processed video will be shown using `cv2.imshow('frame',frame1) and cv2.imshow('res',res1).`

Code is shown below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep 

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1.set(3,640)
cap1.set(4,480)
cap1.set(5,15)


    while(1):

    _, frame1 = cap1.read()
    #hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of white color in HSV
    # change it according to your need !
    lower_white = np.array([150,150,150], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only white colors
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(frame1, lower_white, upper_white)

    kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")

    # Tracking the Red Color
    (_, contours1, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(mask1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for pic, contour1 in enumerate(contours1):
        area1 = cv2.contourArea(contour1)
        #start = time.time()
        if (area1 > 1200):
            print 'white in cam 1'




            #x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            #img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            ellipse1 = cv2.fitEllipse(contour1)
            cv2.ellipse(frame1, ellipse1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            #cv2.putText(frame, "RED color", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255))


    red = cv2.dilate(mask1, kernal)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame1,frame1, mask= mask1)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame1)
    cv2.imshow('res',res1)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My problem is that a few months back, this code was working fine in real-time. But now when I again tried to run the same code, my video didn't run in real-time but a huge time lag is present. For example, when there is a white object in front of the camera, it will take a few minutes to show it as white. In past, when I ran this code, video frame window appears without any time lag but now frame window appear after a few minutes.

Please explain to me how to solve this problem? Why is it so that in past same code was working but now it's not? Is it a problem of python2 or python3 or RaspberryPi?

Comment: The code you show is not correct. The `while` indentation is wrong (the condition un-idiomatic, use `True` instead and lose the parentheses. Same goes for your tuple unpacking). The part that confuses me that you do not contain a `cv2.waitKey(1)` or similar call. That is usually necessary to allow the event system to work, and might explain the observed issue. No idea why it ever worked. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Please disregard my comment about the missing `waitKey`, I managed to not scroll down enough. My bad.